# PHP Rest API post request using Linnworks API

Tags: php, api, rest

I am new to REST APIs and I am trying to get started using the Linnworks API for our order management software. As a starting point I am trying to use a post request to simply get the current stock level of 1 item using it's GUID.

The documentation for this request can be seen here:

http://apidoc.linnworks.net/Home/ApiMethod/GetStockLevel

I have gone through the first stages of the post requests using a userID and password to be issued with a token as explained here:

http://apidoc.linnworks.net/Home/Page/Auth%20Introduction

I have now tried to create a post request using stream_context_create and information from a lot of blog posts I have been reading. I have written the following code but keep getting a blank screen not even a warning or error message. Can anybody see where I am going wrong? I am new to this so I may be missing something major. I have omitted my token for security purposes:

```
<?php

$postdata = array(
    'stockItemId' => 'bb0ef47f-f3fe-47b4-8863-ddfe8bc69b29'
    );

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'header' => 
                    'Authorization: Token my-token-here\r\n'.
                    'Host: eu1.linnworks.net\r\n'.
                    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n'.
                    'Accept-Language: en\r\n',
        'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://eu1.linnworks.net//api/Stock/GetStockLevel',false, $context);

echo $result;
?>
```

When doing a var_dump of each variable I get the following if this helps:

**Var Dump: $postdata**

```
array(1) { ["stockItemId"]=> string(36) "bb0ef47f-f3fe-47b4-8863-ddfe8bc69b29" }
```

**Var Dump: $opts**

```
array(1) { ["http"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "POST" ["protocol_version"]=> float(1.1) ["header"]=> string(162) "Authorization: Token my-token-here\r\nHost: eu1.linnworks.net\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAccept-Language: en\r\n" ["content"]=> array(1) { ["stockItemId"]=> string(36) "bb0ef47f-f3fe-47b4-8863-ddfe8bc69b29" } } }
```

**Var Dump: $context**

```
resource(2) of type (stream-context)
```

**Var Dump: $result**

```
bool(false)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the [Guzzle library](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) to create HTTP requests, IMHO far way easier and flexible.

Comment: Looking add the authorization manual, it looks like the token must be provided by GET instead of an Auth header? I try to call the URL like this: $a = file_get_contents('https://eu1.linnworks.net//api/Stock/GetStockLevel'); When i var_dump a it returns also false, and an error is thrown (Warning: file_get_contents(https://eu1.linnworks.net//api/Stock/GetStockLevel) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized). Maby check your error_reporting level?

Comment: Hi Sanderbee thanks for your help. However, on this page (http://apidoc.linnworks.net/Home/Page/Auth%20Introduction) it does say "The token can be provided in either the Authorization header or the Query string, depending on your requirements." also all the documentation is written with POST at the beginning. I did however try it in the url with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

i have just started developing with Linnworks and there docs are really unhelpful to say the least.

However, there are two important things to note from my experience.  One, to get the AuthorisationByApplication you have to use a different server to return a valid token:

> https://api.linnworks.net/api/Auth/AuthorizeByApplication

And another to request from the application authorised account.  Here is my function to get the accounts categories:

```
$paras = array(
'token' => $u->Token
);

getLinn('Inventory/GetCategories', $paras);

function getLinn($method, $paras)
{
$url = 'https://eu1.linnworks.net/api/' . $method;
$aHttp = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => '',
        'header' => ["Authorization: " . $paras['token'],
            "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
            "Content-Encoding: chunked",
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
    )
);
//print_r($aHttp);
$context = stream_context_create($aHttp);
$contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

return $contents;
}
```

Hope this may help someone in the future :)